# EXISTS inside CASE inside AGGREGATE FUNCTION

Tags: sql, case, aggregate-functions, exists

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
SELECT SUM(
          CASE WHEN (<some_condition> 
                     AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                FROM <tableA> as tA
                                WHERE tA.Id = tB.tAId and
                                <some_other_condition>
                               )
                    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) as <column_name>
FROM <tableB> as tB
```

I need to avoid the use of joins to achieve what I need, because I don't want to count/sum duplicates returned by the results I get through join clauses in this case. When I try to execute my query, I get the following error message:

> "cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Any help appreciated.

> EDIT: I added a possible condition on the WHERE statement only to show I need to relate the columns of the outside table (tableB) with the inside table (tableA)

Here's an example of tableA and tableB and what happens when I JOIN both:

```
tableA:     tableB:          tableA JOIN tableB
Id          Id tAId Time     Id(A) Id(B) taId Time
 1           1    1    5        1     1     1    5
 2           2    2    6        2     2     2    6
 3           3    2   10        2     3     2   10
 4           4    3   11        3     4     3   11
 5           5    4   14        4     5     4   14
             6    4   13        4     6     4   13
             7    4   12        4     7     4   12   
             8    5   10        5     8     5   10
```

So, when I try to count/sum some property (i.e. tableA.Id) from tableA using the results of the JOIN operation as input, I end up counting duplicates. Here's why I can't use JOIN unless I can select DISTINCT elements. I liked the answer that shows this so I'm trying to implement that with no errors.

(Note: I really appreciate all the other answers since they show possible solutions that can fit my situation)

Comment: show your <some condition> s too

Comment: You will get better answers if you describe the result you need clearly, with example data.

Comment: edited. Is there something else I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: indeed. Thanks for the tip, I'll try to inset sample data then.

Comment: The intention of your query is quite unclear.  You should explain what you are trying to do.  Often, a non-functioning query does a poor job of explaining intent.

Comment: Oh, my bad. My intent is to count the number of elements on tableB which Ids also appear in tableA, at least once. I don't intent to count duplicates, just to check the occurrence of the Id in one table in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(
          CASE WHEN (<some_condition> 
                     AND tA.Id IS NOT NULL
                    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) as <column_name>
FROM <tableB> as tB
     JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ta.Id
           FROM <tableA>) as tA ON tA.Id = tB.Id AND <some_other_condition>
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since, as the message says, you cannot use a subquery in an aggregate function (`SUM()`), consider using a join similar to the following:

```
SELECT SUM(
          CASE WHEN (<some_condition> 
                     AND tA.<matching_column> IS NOT NULL
                    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          ) as <column_name>
FROM <tableB> tB
LEFT JOIN <tableA> tA
ON tA.Id = tB.Id
WHERE tA.<some_other_condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple answer from what you provided initiall:

```
SELECT SUM(<column_name>) AS SumColumn
FROM (
        SELECT CASE WHEN <some_condition> AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM <tableA> WHERE <some_other_condition>) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as <column_name>
        FROM <tableB>
    )AS SUB
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is an aggregation query, so the intent appears to be returning one row.  So, just move all the conditions to the `WHERE` clause.  This is my best guess as to your intent:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as <column_name>
FROM <tableB> tB
WHERE (<some_condition> AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM <tableA> as tA
              WHERE tA.Id = tB.Id AND <some_other_condition>
             );
```

Comment: Indeed that could work. And sorry for not making the intention more explicit. If I had to count only one thing, it could be the solution. The problem is that I need to count several things and this EXISTS condition is what differentiates an aggregation of another, so I can't move this condition to the WHERE clause. Nevertheless, if I could check more than one answer, I would certainly check yours too.